# not saving cache in the directory using Ktor HttpCache

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am using Ktor Client for network calls. I want to store the JSON response into cache and need to show those when device has No Internet connection. I have installed `HttpCache` plugins via dependency injection. The cache directory is generating but it is empty.

Below is the code:

```
single<HttpClient> {
  HttpClient {
    ...
    install(HttpCache) {
        val separator = File.separator
        val filepath = "${androidApplication().cacheDir.path}${separator}gp_cache$separator"
        val cacheFile = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(filepath)).toFile()
        publicStorage(FileStorage(cacheFile))         
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The cache directory `gp_cache` created but it is empty. Screenshot attached below:

[device directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS3pB.png)

Please let me know what I have done wrong in this.

Comment: How do you test the caching? What requests do you make to check it?